# How to display the filename of a video/audio/doc file in edit form along with choose file button in angular?

Tags: html, typescript, forms, sass, angular14

I have an edit form with dropdown menu which contains options link, video, audio and document. There is a source column next to it where i want to display the path of each file selected from api. In case of link I want to display the link as it is, where as in case of other files the file name along with  choose file button also should able to edit it. This is the method which I tried where the no file chosen is hidden using css. But when I try to insert a new entry the existing video file is getting erased from Database. Can anyone help me how to populate the source field with video file name.[![

```html
<td class="path_{{i}}">
                                                  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="trainingModulescon(i).controls['type'].value">
                                                    <!-- Show link for material type '1' (Link) -->
                                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'1'">
                                                      <a [href]="trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].value">{{ trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].value }}</a>
                                                    </ng-container>
                                                    <!-- Show file input and file name for other material types -->
                                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                                                      <input type="file" formControlName="source"  name="source" (change)="handleFileChange($event, i)">
                                                        <span class="source">{{modulesData[i]['SOURCE'] }}</span>  
                                                    </ng-container>
                                                  </ng-container>
                                                  </td>
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
    width:89px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.courseid = history.state;   

    this.apicall.GetEmpCourseDtls(this.courseid).subscribe((res) => {
      this.courseData = res[0];   
         
        // Populate the form controls with the received data
        this.courseForm.setValue({
          course:this.courseData.COURSE_ID,
          department: this.courseData.DEPARTMENT,          
          title: this.courseData.TITLE,
          start_date: this.datepipe.transform(this.courseData.START_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
          end_date: this.datepipe.transform(this.courseData.END_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),

          description: this.courseData.DESCRIPTION,
          assessment_status: JSON.stringify(this.courseData.ASSESSMENT_STATUS),
          timeduration: this.courseData.TIME_DURATION,
          Mflag: " ",
          created_by: this.courseData.CREATED_BY,
        TrainingModules:[]
         });

       
      });
      this.apicall.GetEmpMaterialDtls(this.courseid).subscribe((res) => {      
       
         // Populate the training modules
         this.modulesData = res;
          alert(JSON.stringify(res));
          if (this.modulesData && this.modulesData.length > 0) {
            
            this.modulesData.forEach((module:any) => {
            let src="";
            if(module.TYPE=="1")
            src= module.SOURCE;
              this.TrainingModules().push(
                this.fb.group({
                  material: module.MATERIAL_NAME,                  
                  type: module.TYPE,
                  source: src,
                  duration: module.TIME_DURATION

                })
              );
            });
          }
      });
    }
    handleFileChange(event: any, index: number) {
      const files = event.target.files;
      // this.file = files;
      if (files && files.length > 0) {
        const file = files[0];
        //  this.file = file;
        this.courseForm.get('TrainingModules')?.get(index.toString())?.get('source')?.setValue(file);
      }
    }
   

}
```

My edit form is like this.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwfyc.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwfyc.png)